# How to return more than 100 results from Google Search on Android

Tags: android

I'm getting results from Google Search when I write a word. But I am getting less than 100 results. I want to get 500 results. How can I do this?

```
try {
    Response response = null;
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("http://www.google.com.tr/search?q="+ URLEncoder.encode(params[0],"utf-8")+"&num=500")
        .build();

    response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    return response.body().string();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return null;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no way to return more than 100 results with one query. The `num` parameter in the URL can be anything up to 100, go over that and it'll still return 100 results.

See this [guide to search URL parameters](https://moz.com/ugc/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-google-search-parameters).

However, you may be able to do a workaround by using the `start` parameter - this will return the next 'page' of results.

For example, get the first 100:

```
https://www.google.ie/search?q=google+search+parameters&num=100
```

Then get the next 100:

```
https://www.google.ie/search?q=google+search+parameters&num=100&start=100
```

It should be easy enough to construct a loop to do this:

```
int num = 100;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    String url = "http://www.google.com.tr/search?q="
        + URLEncoder.encode(params[0],"utf-8")
        + "&num=" + num
        + "&start=" + (num * i);
    // Construct the request object and make the request here
}
```

You'll have to process each set of 100 results separately, but it should do the trick.

Hope this helps!